# NoClassDefFoundError while running java UDF from DB2

Tags: java, db2, user-defined-functions

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sourceforge/jgeocoder/us/AddressParser

I am trying to create a java UDF from DB2.

I have a function within a Java Class which in turn is in a JAR(say JAR1). My Function references external functions which are residing within a different JAR(say JAR2).

TRY1:

- Added JAR2 to the classpath of my MANIFEST file.
- I have registered JAR1 with **sqlj.db2_install_jar** Proc.
- FAIL

TRY2:

- I have registered JAR2 with **sqlj.db2_install_jar** Proc.
- Found the location of the JAR in DB2 server after install process.
- Added JAR2 to the classpath of my MANIFEST file.
- I have registered JAR1 with **sqlj.db2_install_jar** Proc.
- FAIL

Can any one point my in the right direction here??

Thanks

Comment: How do you call `db_install_jar()`? Specifically, how do you pass the BLOB locator parameter to it? What is your Db2 version and platform?

Comment: @mustaccio I store the jar file to a table as blob and then pass it into the function using a sub-query. DB2 Version 10.0 Platform linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

I had a class name and a package name which was same which I believe had created some kind of ambiguity. Changed it and everything seems to be working as expected.

I have also created a runnable jar which combined the 2 jars to a single one.